# java.util.NoSuchElementException when scanning user input with nextInt()

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number is " + a);
    }
}
```

When running this code it just gives me a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error. I've searched for answers and no, I've never used `sc.close()` in my code.

I've even re-installed the compiler and restarted my computer but it still gives me the same error despite running other code normally.

I'm using Netbeans 11.1 and JDK version 13.

Comment: it works very well in my computer. :(, can you paste all the error info in ?

Comment: I'm aware that the issue is in my compiler but I have no idea why. I did the default installation and it compiles other code normally, but it breaks when scanning for user input. Weird.